# SQL search for complex string within a row

Tags: sql, t-sql

Ok so I have a database row with a specified string in for example `i am here`.

I want to know how I could match this row (in a T-SQL query) if for example my input was `hello i am here in this bright room`.

To be clearer and get a better answer hopefully, here is a rough example:

Table:

```
1 | i am there |
2 | i am here |
3 | i am not here |
```

Problem:

I have the input `hello i am here in this bright room` - this should return a match to row 2 above only as only row 2 contains `i am here` definitively whilst the others contain the characters for `i am here` but with subtle differences.

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated. I would like to do this all in SQL so I can create a stored procedure for the above.

Comment: This might also get you there but the answer from RedFilter is much slicker.   I think you could get there with REGX via User-Defined Functions. This is an article from SQL 2005 but it is a good article. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @InputString VARCHAR(100);
SET @InputString = 'hello i am here in this bright room';

SELECT *
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE CHARINDEX(YourColumn, @InputString) <> 0;
```

Comment: Thanks @joe-stefanelli this one works well however it will also give smaller matches for example, if I just wanted to match "i am here" but also had a row in the table with just "i am" it would bring back a match for both rows. For the context I need to use it in this hopefully won't be a problem but if you know of a way to stop that behaviour it would be good to know for completeness.

Comment: @Aracas Before we could stop that behavior, we'd need to discuss how you've determined that "i am here" is a valid match but "i am" is not a valid match. What criteria do you use to make that decision?

Comment: Thanks for your response @joe-stefanelli, basically the idea will be that specific sentences will be stored within rows of the table; a "input" will then be a sentence which will need to match the closest possible of all the rows therefore "i am here" is a better match than just "i am". I'm guessing that a simple SELECT TOP(1) would do the trick?

Comment: @Aracas: `TOP 1` will return one result but really isn't sufficient if your requirement is to find the "closest possible" match. If that's the case, you're looking at some pretty sophisticated searching that is beyond ordinary SQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @input as varchar
set @input = 'hello i am here in this bright room'
select *
from MyTable
where @input like '%' + MyCol + '%'
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: The problem statement is to search on "hello i am here in this bright room"

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help but the input is "hello i am here in this bright room" so i cannot search for "%i am here%" specifically without losing the rest of the string which may match a different row. for example "bright room" may be matched by a different row.

Comment: hi @RedFilter, thanks for your update, seems a bit closer to what i was thinking however it still doesn't brink back a match? is there something i am missing?